# entity framework when many to many is holding data

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4, entity-relationship, ef4-code-only

I'm using Entity Framework CTP5.

I have a schema like this:

- A group contains many textdescriptions.
- A textdescriptions has many texts.
- A Language has many texts.

So there are 4 tables.
**Groups** one-to-many **DEscriptions** many-to-many **Texts** many-to-one **Languages**.

[image: my model]

So I have a many-to-many relationship where the relation also holds data.

Definitions of Text and TextDescription ( since we can query on the Id for Group and Languages I havent added them here )

```
public class Text
{
    public int TextID { get; set; }
    public int TextDescriptionID { get; set; }
    public int LanguageID { get; set; }
    public string OriginalText { get; set; }
    public bool IsValid { get; set; }
    public DateTime Added { get; set; }
    public DateTime Updated { get; set; }
    public Language Language { get; set; }
    public TextDescription TextDescription { get; set; }

    public static Text GetMissingText(string input)
    {
        Text text = new Text();
        text.OriginalText = "Missing: " + input;
        text.IsValid = true;
        text.TextDescription = new TextDescription()
                               {
                                   IsStatic = true,
                                   Name = input,
                                   IsMultiline = false,
                               };

        return text;
    }
}

public class TextDescription
{
    public int TextDescriptionId { get; set; }
    public int TextDescriptionGroupId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool UseHtml { get; set; }
    public bool IsMultiline { get; set; }
    public bool IsStatic { get; set; }

    public TextDescriptionGroup TextDescriptionGroup { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Text> Texts { get; set; }

    public static TextDescription GetNewItem(int textDescriptionGroupId)
    {
        var item = new TextDescription();
        item.Name = item.Description = "n/a";
        item.UseHtml = item.IsMultiline = item.IsMultiline = false;
        item.TextDescriptionGroupId = textDescriptionGroupId;
        return item;
    }
}
```

When adding either a new language or a new text is inserted ... the many to many relation is not inserted into the database. (Think it would be a bad idea, so in the end, if thats the only solution, I could be able to that)

So how do I handle this in a smart way when I need to fetch all the **text** for a specific group from the database, but also get the translation if there are one for that languages.

I can't start fra the translation object, since its possible its not there. If I start to query from the Text entity ... how do I only select one language without getting all languages first.

```
 repo.Find(x => 
           x.GroupId == groupId && 
           x.Translation.Any(a => a.LanguageID == id.Value)
 );
```

I'm lost here ... any there any smart way ... so I wont have to query the database for all the Texts ... and then a query for each item ... to see if there are a translation? or else just make a new empty one.

In SQL I would do it like this:

```
SELECT TD.Name, T.OriginalText FROM TextDescriptions TD
LEFT JOIN Texts T ON TD.TextDescriptionId = T.TextDescriptionId
WHERE TextDescriptionGroupId = 41 AND ISNULL(T.LanguageId, 1) = 1
```

The above SQL will give me the elements even if there is not record now, I get a NULL for these values. I could then handle that it my code and avoid lazy load.

But can I get the same behavior in Entity Framework. I could see there would be some problems maybe for EF4 to do the mapping ... since I'm going from TextDesciptions to Texts ... and TextDesciptions have a List of Texts ... but here ... I only want either 1 or NULL, or just a new Entity that havent been added to the database yet.

Looking forward to some interesting answers.

mvh

Comment: You need to show the code that does not work as expected (i.e. *When adding either a new language or a new text is inserted ... the many to many relation is not inserted into the database.*). Also, we need to see you full object model as well as any fluent API that you may have. Thanks.

Comment: The problem is that it works as it should and how I would expect it to work. I'm looking for a way to do a left join. I can show it in SQL, but not sure how I would do it with linq, other then it would generate lots of lazy load.

Comment: I'm using EF4 ... I'm not sure what you want to see. I hope the posted picture gives you an idea. Maybe I can create my model in VS. Not sure if that will help. But do ask if more information is needed. Maybe a better design idea for the table structure.

Comment: Thanks for the update but like I said, I wanted to see your object model like the definitions of the classes such as Language, TextDescriptions, etc...

Comment: Added the definition for both Text and TextDescription.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now ... if no other solution is found I will be running the follow SQL script to insert empty records. This way I'm sure the record is there when a user wants to edit it and dont have to ensure its there before saving it. Maybe also avoiding some naste Linq query.

I only have to run this SQL 2 places. When adding a new Language or new a new TextDesciption.

```
INSERT INTO Texts 
SELECT TD.TextDescriptionId, L.LanguageId, '', 0, GETDATE(), GETDATE(), L.TwoLetterISOLanguageName 
FROM TextDescriptions TD 
INNER JOIN Languages L ON 1 = 1 
LEFT JOIN Texts T ON 
T.TextDescriptionId = TD.TextDescriptionId AND 
T.LanguageId = L.LanguageId 
WHERE TextId IS NULL
```